# Are there any technical obstacles for implementing `function* ()` syntax

Tags: javascript

In Python we have `yield` which is very similar to that one which [is proposed](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3agenerators) in ES6 (in fact, pythonic co-routines were the main source of inspiration for implementing co-routines in

I wonder what are the reasons for choosing a separate `function* ()` syntax for generators compared to just defining "regular" functions with yeilds - just like in python by the way? I'm talking strictly of technical issues and peculiarities. Why it had been decided that a separate form will be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because code that uses `yield` normally as variable would change its meaning:

```
function test() {
    var yield = 3;
    return yield + 2 //in current javascript this means return 5 
                     //but if yield syntax was enabled for all 
                     //functions then it would secretly change meaning
}
```

Comment: so all these new syntax had been introduced only not to introduce new keyword?

Comment: @shabunc yes, you can't just introduce changes that will break existing websites

Comment: You can't introduce a new keyword. That would break code that uses that keyword as an identifier. You *have* to use syntax that is currently illegal.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, from this actually follows that instead of introducing new keywords we are doomed to invent new syntax - ain't it a bit dangerous? Though I'm not arguing, all I was asking about is technical reasons, and I guess I've already find the answer)

Comment: @shabunc: Correct, and this is a very big reason why languages accumulate technical debt and cruft over time. You're stuck with your short sighted or poor decisions forever, because you can't make breaking changes.

Comment: Yes. That's the problem with success. People actually write programs in your language, and get angry when those programs break. The only solution to that problem is to fail ;-)

Comment: @JörgWMittag: No, not the only solution.  Some languages resolve that by breaking your program.  For example, Python 3 had several breaking changes.  Alternatively, you can allow users to specify which version of the language they are using.  In the case of javascript, [the MDN JS 1.7 page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FNew_in_JavaScript%2F1.7) documents the use of the `version=1.7` suffix.

Comment: Of course you can introduce a new keyword without breaking old code, you just have to make it contextual (like `yield` in C#) so that no previously legal program is parsed as using the keyword. Note that "contextual" does not mean "context-sensitive" in either the CS sense or the commonly used (wrong) sense.

Comment: @Brian The difference is that you have to choose to run Python 3 on your code.  With Javascript, you can't choose the engine used to run it - visitors to your page do.

Comment: @Izkata: That's only partly true.  As my comment states, you can enable breaking JS 1.7 changes by using a `;version=1.7` suffix in your url.  The bigger problem in JS is users who use older versions of JS, rather than new JS users breaking old JS code.  Of course, that is not the issue the OP is concerned with.